# Possible to throw an error when trying to modify frozen object

Tags: javascript, immutability

If I run some code like this:

```
var a = { prop: 123 };
Object.freeze(a);
a.prop = 456;
```

As expected, `a.prop` is still "123" because the object is frozen. What I'm wondering is, is it possible to get the runtime to throw an error when trying to modify a property of a frozen object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As so often, the secret sauce is to [`"use strict"` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) for not ignoring the exception:

```js
"use strict";
var a = Object.freeze({ prop: 123 });
a.prop = 456;
```